# Can Pymongo pass all mongoshell commandds

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongo-shell

I am trying to use python for working with `MongoDB`. To be simple as possible.

I tried **db.getUser() with Pymongo** :

```
  db = client[database_name]

  db.command("getUsers")
```

and I received following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: no such command: 'getUsers'
```

I would appreciate if somebody guide me through !!!

Please note that, I already manged to use some native mongoshell commands such as "createUser" , "dropUser" in a same manner described above.

Best,

Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

The [mongo documenation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getUser/) states:

```
db.getUser() wraps the usersInfo: <username> command.
```

Looking at [that documenation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/#dbcmd.usersInfo) reveals we can use the command as follows:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import dumps

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Create a test user
db.command('createUser', 'user', pwd='password', roles=['read'])

command_result = db.command(
    {
        'usersInfo': {'user': 'user', 'db': 'mydatabase'},
        'showPrivileges': True
    }
)
print(command_result)
# Optionally pretty format the output
print(dumps(command_result, indent=4))
```